# Does DXA Search module support sorting?

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.7

I have configured DXA(1.7) Search Module with AWS cloud search in our project. Now my question is "**does it support sorting by default?**"

I have tried with below url, It is neither breaking my view nor showing the expected result -

```
http://dev.stg.com/en/search.html?q=coffee&sort=date
```

Please confirm.

Comment: BTW: might be nicer to use an extensionless URL (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sort` parameter will get passed to AWS CloudSearch, but note that AWS CloudSearch poses restrictions on what and how you can sort. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/sorting-results.html

In particular: *"You use the sort parameter to specify the field or expression you want to use to sort the results. You must explicitly specify the sort direction along with the name of the field or expression. For example, sort=year asc or sort=year desc"*

Comment: An up vote and accepting the answer counts as "thanks" on StackExchange sites. ;-)